# Integrated SDK behave differently after PlayStore app bundling

Tags: java, android

1. I integrated 3rd party SDK to my Android app.
2. I tested staging and release build APK, no problem. The build is done using bitrise/BETA by crashlytics.
3. I downloaded the release app from Google Play Store.
4. The SDK throws persistent error/exception that does not appear during 2.

The SDK developer deducted that the cause may be from the missing checksum, which is generated using this piece of code:

```
mChecksumMD5 = Util.calculateMD5(new File(mContext.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir+"/libxyz.so"));
```

I suspect it may be due to app bundling, which is not present during build via bitrise/BETA. I tried to use bundled app using bundle tools (https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases) for staging build and it doesn't have any problem (bitrise staging vs bundled staging are all ok). So is there something different about the app bundling happening in Google Play Store? What may cause this unexpected exception?

Comment: App Bundling on the play store is a bit diffrent to my understanding you upload the bundle and it generates an APK from that, try building an apk from android studio and uploading that instead of an App Bundle

Comment: The error is probably a compiling error on googles side, Also check to see if the bundle is made correctly and contains all the necessary data, had a problem with an app bundle where a library was not included in the app bundle and I just rebuild the App in a new project and it worked